# What could cause textures to be black in the fragment shader?

Tags: javascript, glsl, textures, webgl

I've been working a bit with WebGL but it seems I can't manage to display textures any more. The output of the fragment shader is always black (the silhouette is visible).

I know this problem may occur with textures that aren't a power of two. Unfortunately mine are (256x256). Besides, I did get them working before at some point (but I changed too much to backtrack the problem).

EDIT:
I've greatly simplified my program and as suggested by gman used WebGL Inspector (great tip btw).
Textures look fine from WebGL Inspector. 
I was just about to post the whole code when I noticed that while

```
var textureUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
console.log(textureUniformLocation);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, neheTexture);
gl.uniform1i(textureUniformLocation, 0);
```

does not work, adding `alert(textureUniformLocation);` after `console.log(...)` makes the texture appear...
What I now want to know is: Is my graphics card doing drugs?

EDIT2: It will work if I put a simple string in the alert as well.

The only reason I can think of this would occur is either bad memory management or multiple execution threads. Neither of them are the case here afaik. What kind of thing could even cause such a problem in javascript?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try changing it to `gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(...).rgb, 1.0);` just to make sure it's not that your alpha is zero?

Comment: same problem, would have been surprised if that had worked though since the textures worked previously.

Comment: I'd start adding some `console.log()` statements. Print your uniform locations (make sure none of them are null). Maybe try the `WebGL Inspector`. Setting `gl_FragColor` to a constant like `vec4(0,1,0,1)` makes green right? Have you got more than one shader program? Did yu call `gl.useProgram` on the correct program? Start with a sample that works and start pasting your code into it until it stops working.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely start using WebGL inspector.
I've only got one uniform location now (the sampler) and one attribute array.
I only have one program and setting colour constants in shaders work as I'd expect. Something seems to be off with the uniform location though, I've edited my post with a new finding.

Comment: Adding an alert suggests your texture has not loaded yet. Images are loaded asynchronously. (oh, I see bjorke mentioned this below). Add a console.log("loaded") to your image.onload event as well as a console.log("rendered") where you call gl.drawXXX and you'll see the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inspector sees the textures, then... they are *probably* loading. Is the behavior consistent in both Chrome and Firefox? The reported behavior about alert() makes me think that perhaps the render happened before the texture load and the alert() causes a refresh (after the texture load).

Also make sure that this isn't a problem with vertex attributes like vertex color or degenerate UV coordinates.

Comment: They don't load in Chrome at all, behaviour in Firefox is as described above. WebGL Inspector shows textures in both.

Maybe the image didn't load yet, that happens asynchronously afaik. Any way to make the main 'thread' wait before drawing?

Comment: Yep that was it. Image hadn't finished loading before the draw function was called. I used to have moving object so I'd render multiple times so the problem didn't show previously. I think I'll go post a warning on the tutorial I followed.